# Definition of the space $L^p(\partial \Omega)$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry

Let $\Omega$ be an open set. I have studied the spaces $L^p(\Omega)$ for $1\leq p \leq \infty.$

Let $\partial \Omega$ denote the boundary of $\Omega.$
What do we mean by $f \in L^p({\partial \Omega}),$ more precisely what do we mean by $\int\limits_{\partial \Omega}f(x)dx.$

A clean and self contained definition(assuming no background in differential geometry)  will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is like the line integrals and surface integrals you learned in multivariable calculus. If $\partial\Omega$ is smooth, you can locally write it as a graph, say $x_n = \phi(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$ and write this integral as $\int_U f(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},\phi(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}))\sqrt{1+\|\nabla\phi\|^2}dx_1\dots dx_{n-1}$. You can figure out the $L^p$ part for yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

When $\Omega$ is merely "an open set" ... even in $\mathbb R$ ... there is no common meaning for this.  In case $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^d$ (or a $d$-dimensional manifold $M$) and $\partial \Omega$ is a rectifiable surface of dimension $d-1$ in $M$, then we take the $(d-1)$-dimensional measure $\mu$ on $\partial \Omega$ and use that to define $L^p(\partial\Omega) =L^p(\partial\Omega,\mu)$.

In any other case, I would expect the writer to explain the meaning before using the notation $L^p(\partial \Omega)$.